# Cannot clone git repository in command line script task in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created azure devops pipeline where I need to download code from another git repository. As per recommended solution I've read somewhere, I added a command line script task with git clone command. Unfortunatelly this doesn't work.

The error that I get is:
remote: TF200016: The following project does not exist: My0Test0Project. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/myCompany/My0Test0Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core/' not found

My project in Azure has spaces, maybe there is a bug in azure related to that? Does anybody knows any workarounds?

This is some code that I have tried already:

```
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: Basic bXl1c2VyOmxtNjRpYTYzb283bW1iYXp1bnpzMml2eWxzbXZoZXE2azR1b3V2bXdzbnl5b3R5YWlnY2E=" clone https://dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%20Test%20Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core
```

```
git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" clone https://dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%20Test%20Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core
```

```
git clone https://oauth:lm64ia63oo7mmbazunzs2ivylsmvheq6k4uouvmwsnyyotyaigca@dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%20Test%20Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core
```

```
git clone https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%20Test%20Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core
```

Comment: Did you enable "Allow access to oauth token" in your build?

Comment: Yes, I did, I also tried both personal access token (string64 encoded and not) and System.AccessToken values

Comment: If you run this command in a command prompt, you have to escape the percentage sign for the space as ``%%20``. So, try ``git clone https://%SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%@dev.azure.com/mycompany/My%%20Test/_git/whatever``

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because you need to add the system access token so that Azure can have access to the external repo. (your credentials need access to that repo)

**NOTE:**

I wrapped my URL in quotes to escape the % signs in the URL string because Powershell treats those as variables otherwise.

```
- powershell: |
    git clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)" "https://{YOUR PIPELINE URL}"
    displayName: '{YOUR PIPELINE NAME}'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue from a bash script and solved it by escaping the `%` character with `%%`.

So, you can use this :

`git clone https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%%20Test%%20Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this from Powershell task and it worked 
Its very simple just use

```
- powershell: |
   git config user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
   git config user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
   git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  clone  https://<org_Name>.visualstudio.com/<project_name>/_git/<repository_name>;
  displayName: "<your task display name>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change your Command Line task to something like this one?

```
git clone --single-branch --branch $(branchName) https://$(gitUserName):$(gitPassword)@dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%20Test%20Project/_git
```

Where $(gitUserName) and $(gitPassword) configured as [Alternate git credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops#alternate-credentials) in
[your Azure DevOps account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pxmH.png).

Also wanted to ask about ending of git repository URL:
".../_git/Service.Azure.Core", you are trying to specify which folder to clone or maybe working directory? You can also try your previous code without that ending, just 
`https://dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%20Test%20Project/_git`

Answer (score -2):

This will happen when your path has space characters in it.

The workaround for this is to not use `%20` in your URL and use actual space characters instead. Since your URL now has space characters, also make sure that your URL is wrapped inside double quotes.

So your

`git clone https://dev.azure.com/myCompany/My%20Test%20Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core/`

should be

`git clone "https://dev.azure.com/myCompany/My Test Project/_git/Service.Azure.Core/"`

Comment: I tried this, but I got: The requested URL returned error: 400

Comment: Since % is an escape character, you must use %%20

Comment: ADO reports -- fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/org/_git/my project/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL