# Run Git Commands as Azure devops Agent task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, build-pipeline

Can any one help me how to run git command in my build pipeline. I want to merge my dev branch in to staging branch before start build the solution to deployment. I have add command line task and run git commands but its not giving any result from GIT[image]

Answer (score 3):

This the way how I'm accomplishing interaction with the git repo directly in the yaml pipeline bash command

```
cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s

# Update Git User
git config --global user.email $(GITHUB_EMAIL)
git config --global user.name $(GITHUB_NAME)

# Switch to clone from branch
git checkout -b $(FROM_BRANCH) origin/$(FROM_BRANCH)

# do your code manipulations here then push them upstream

git push origin -f $(TO_BRANCH)
```

Comment: this is what i m expecting. will try this and let you know with update.thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I  want to merge my dev branch in to staging branch

You could try to use `git merge` command to merge.

Here is an example:

```
git remote add Reponame https://PAT@dev.azure.com/orgNAME/project name/_git/Reponame
git checkout -b staging
git pull
git merge  remotes/origin/dev
git push Reponame  staging  -f
```

You could directly use this command in the `Command Line Task`.

Then the `Dev branch` will merge to the `Staging branch`.

You could get the following build log.

[image: Build log]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question was asked. But I'd like to introduce an alternative way (from an example in the official documentation) for those seeking to run code before git checkout in a pipeline:

```
steps:
- script: |
    git config --global --add filter.lfs.required true
  displayName: Configure LFS for use with submodules
- checkout: self
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally you have two pipelines one for the PR, to check that all your changes compile without error, And then the CI build that compile and publish the artifact or make the deploy if you don't have releases.

So the CI build only is triggered when the Master branch change. So you don't have to  make the merge whit a task, you have to make the merge and then launch the build pipeline.

Comment: First carefully read my question.no issue with building the solution and publishing artifacts. all working fine.its not the problem for me. all i need is to create one task for merge two branch (run git command). once release done i need to update target branch

Comment: Oh, sorry man, if the other user's answer doesn't work for you I think you can try it with the Powershell task like in the answer of this questions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833316/cannot-clone-git-repository-in-command-line-script-task-in-azure-devops-pipeline