# Azure Pipeline git clone cannot handle spaces in repo URL

Tags: git, azure-devops

Using Azure Pipelines, I am trying to do "git clone --mirror" on a self-hosted Windows agent.

It works if I use bash on a MS-hosted agent. But my self-hosted agent doesn't have bash right now, so I want to use script instead:

```
script: 'git clone --mirror https://dev.azure.com/MyCompany/Project%20Name/_git/MyRepo'
```

But I get this error:

> remote: TF200016: The following project does not exist: Project0Name.
> Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project
> exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server. fatal: repository
> 'https://dev.azure.com/MyCompany/Project0Name/_git/MyRepo/' not found

In the error message, the URL-encoded space in the project name has been replaced with a '0'. So it cannot find the repo since the URL is now wrong.

This error appears with both the MS-hosted agent and my self-hosted agent.

The issue seems to be the same as here:
[Cannot clone git repository in command line script task in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833316/cannot-clone-git-repository-in-command-line-script-task-in-azure-devops-pipeline)

Why does the URL get changed in this way? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in the link above. The '%' character needs to be escaped like so:

```
script: 'git clone --mirror "https://dev.azure.com/MyCompany/Project%%20Name/_git/MyRepo"'
```

Also, I added double quotes, not sure if that makes a difference though.