# Docker: When setting up a development environment through the UI it is not possible to connect to the remote repository

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I am trying to setup a development environment using Docker Desktop 4.7.1 (77678). I want to connect this environment directly to the remote project. This remote project is source version controlled by Git in an Azure DevOps. The setup process fails at the first step and it is not possible to proceed.

**The error message:**

> warning: invalid credential line: fatal: Cannot determine the
> organization name for this 'dev.azure.com' remote URL. Ensure the
> `credential.useHttpPath` configuration value is set, or set the
> organization name as the user in the remote URL '{org}@dev.azure.com'.

**The URL structure:**

```
https://{org}@dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_git/{repo}
```

It is possible to generate credentials in Azure DevOps when accessing cloning function but it is unclear to me how this can be supplied to Docker.

I have seen other *similar* questions where the underlying problem is the same. These questions all relate to Visual Studio I am unable to apply the recommended answer steps in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to create a personal access token in Azure DevOps (from the user settings) and use that token in my URL.
I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67262459/1121854

`https://{org}:{token}@dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_git/{repo}`

This allowed Docker Desktop to authenticate.